# VBA importing COM-registered dll and calling constructor with arguments

Tags: vba, dll, com

Is it possible to reference a COM-registered DLL and then create objects that require arguments in the constructor in VBA code?

I'm successfully referenced the tlb in Access 2013 (64-bit) that was registered with `regasm`, and I've managed to create a simple object that doesn't need arguments in the constructor.

From what I read, it is not. Do I now face major refactoring?

Comment: Do you specifically *need* to manipulate the objects in VBA? I ask because the TLBs can be a nightmare when it comes to versions and updates, and I personally avoid them at all costs when developing Office addins. Instead, I create methods in .NET, accessible from VBA calls, and leave all the manipulation of objects inside .NET, with a method to do everything I need. It means I don't need to use regasm but can dynamically call the methods without strongly typing them. Ping me if you want to discuss it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be "major".  You simply need a factory method, one that takes all the arguments you need to construct the object.  For example:

```
public class Foo {
    internal Foo(int arg1, string arg2) {
       // etc...
    }
    // Other methods and properties
    //...
}

public class FooFactory {
    public Foo Create(int arg1, string arg2) {
        return new Foo(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

And now you simply use FooFactory.Create() in your VBA code.